# Visualisation data as Hierarchical graph using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Good evening,
Hope you all doing well,

I want to draw a Hierarchical graph using networkx

I do a simple example like this :

```js
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['banana', 'apple', 'cherry'],
    'B': ['apple', 'banana', 'avocado'],
    'C': ['apple', 'manga', 'orange']
})

G = nx.DiGraph()

# loop through each column (level) and create nodes and edges
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    # get unique values and their counts in the column
    values, counts = df[col].value_counts(sort=True).index, df[col].value_counts(sort=True).values
    # add nodes to the graph for each unique value in the column, sorted by frequency of occurrence
    for j in range(len(counts)):
        G.add_node(values[j], count=counts[j], layer=i, subset=col)
    # add edges between adjacent nodes in the column
    for j in range(len(values)-1):
        G.add_edge(values[j], values[j+1])

# set the position of each node in a layered layout
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G, subset_key="subset")

# create a color map for the nodes based on their level
color_map = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 'black', 'pink']

# draw nodes, edges, and labels for each level
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    nodes = [n for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['layer'] == i]
    node_sizes = [d['count'] * 50 for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['layer'] == i]
    node_colors = [color_map[i]] * len(nodes)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_size=node_sizes, node_color=node_colors)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), edge_color='gray')
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels={n: n for n in nodes})

# turn off axis and show the graph
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

And that the output of example and it's correct that's what i want
[image]

But when i try to apply this code on my own data like this

```js
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.DiGraph()



# loop through each column (level) and create nodes and edges
for i, col in enumerate(data_cleaned.columns):
    # get unique values and their counts in the column
    values, counts = data_cleaned[col].value_counts(sort=True).index, data_cleaned[col].value_counts(sort=True).values
    # add nodes to the graph for each unique value in the column, sorted by frequency of occurrence
    for j in range(len(counts)):
        G.add_node(values[j], count=counts[j], layer=i, subset=col)
    # add edges between adjacent nodes in the column
    for j in range(len(values)-1):
        G.add_edge(values[j], values[j+1])

# set the position of each node in a layered layout
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G, subset_key="subset")

# create a color map generator that creates a new color for each column
def color_gen():
    while True:
        for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 'black', 'pink']:
            yield color
color_map = color_gen()

# draw nodes, edges, and labels for each level
for i, col in enumerate(data_cleaned.columns):
    nodes = [n for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['layer'] == i]
    node_sizes = [d['count'] * 50 for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['layer'] == i]
    node_colors = [next(color_map)] * len(nodes)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_size=node_sizes, node_color=node_colors)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), edge_color='gray')
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels={n: n for n in nodes})

# turn off axis and show the graph
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I got an unclear output
[image]

But the output i need is that :
[image]

And that data i use :

[image]

Please i need your help

Thanks in advance